# Sobolev injections in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

a) Let $a<b$. Prove there exists an universal contant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(a, b)} \leq C\|u\|_{H^{1}(a, b)} \quad \forall u \in H^{1}(a, b)
$$

b) Let $a<b$. Prove that the injection $H^{1}(a, b) \rightarrow L^{\infty}(a, b)$ is compact.

c) Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ a bounded open set with boundary of class $C^{1} .$ Prove that there no exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq C\|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \quad \forall u \in H^{1}(\Omega)
$$

So I proved the part a) indeed the constant is independet from $p$ in this case $p=2.$ For b) I have no idea because I saw the same problem with the compact $[a,b]$ but for that problem the solution used the Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem so compactness is important, so I have no idea how to prove b).
And c) is also a mystery.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please do not forget to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

You said you can do b) with compact [a,b]. This approach can be salvaged because you can extend an $H^1$ function from $(a,b)$ to $[a,b]$ as a (Hölder) continuous function.

For c) try to construct a radially symmetric singular function whose $H^1$ norm is finite.

Comment: I had never heard of radially symmetric singular function is something standard for this kind of problems? Where can I find this class of examples?

Comment: There is nothing special it just means something like $\log(x^2+y^2)$ or $\log$ replaced by another function. Do the computation yourself.

Comment: I found anothe example : Let $\Omega=B\left(0 ; \frac{1}{2}\right) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} .$ Let
$$
u(x)=\log \log \frac{2}{|x|}, x \neq 0
$$
Then $u \in H^{1}(\Omega),$ i.e. $p=2=N,$ but clearly $u \notin L^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Comment: How do you solve the part a)?

Comment: @Newinmaths This is different from your other question. It wouldn't  help.